# iPhone UIButton with shadow/border on one side and rounded corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, shadow

I am trying to create the following button on iPhone without success.

I have seen answers in stackoverflow but I can't get the same result.

Its basically one plain color and a shadow on the bottom that continues the rounded corner.

[image]

Comment: Simplest is to use images. Are you trying to do it programmatically? If so, look into `drawRect:` drawing and redrawing when state changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try making this button using photoshop. And use that image as a backgroundImage for your button

Answer (score 0):

Corner radius can be achieved by doing this:

```
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = yourDesiredRadius;
```

The border is a bit harder to achieve. I'd recommend you just use an image for this and use it as the background image of your button.
You can set the background image in the Interface Builder. Or, programmatically:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
[self.button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, the best way to do that kind of buttons is using a background image for Normal state and Highlighted state:

```
self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "buttonBackground"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pressedButtonBackground"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

This is how they will look:
[image]

[image]

Here are both images in blue tone:

[buttonBackground.pdf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00477452016723436767) and [pressedButtonBackground.pdf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04719691434554839983)

If you want to use those images for any size, you could slice the images like following:

[image]

[image]